# Testing inter and intra variability of 4 different scanners for 10 patients

Tags: mixed-model, anova, variance

I am a neuroscientist with statistical skills that need improvement and I want to test the variability between and within 4 different scanners. I have a population of 10 patients who underwent 2 scans (10 minutes apart, so repetitive scans) in each of the 4 scanners. i have a total of 80 scans (so again: 2 scans, 4 scanners, 10 patients). I analyzed brain structures (corrected for age) in these scans with 2 different software.

I wanted to use the package `lmer4` from R to look at:

1. the variability between scanners
2. the variability within scanners
3. the effect of the patient itself on the scanner
4. the variability between the software

I've come up with this so far, for example for the brain structure: whole brain

```
mymodel1 <- lmer(whole_brain ~ scanner + (1|patientID), data = dataset1)
```

this says that scanner is a fixed effect and the patient is the only random effect right?

And this:

```
mymodel2 <- lmer(whole_brain ~ scanner + (1+scanner|patientID), data = dataset1)
```

to look at the difference in patient correlated to the scanner.

How do I proceed?

Comment: It seems to me that the "variability within scanners" might be accounted for by both subjects and repeated scans, which means that (2) and (3) have to be clarified somehow.